# How to serialize IList<object> to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Having an `IList<NameValue>` nameValueList, I need to convert that list to string for sending to aspx file as json. But because this happens in a project that does not have reference to **system.web.script** or **system.web.mvc**, i should use another way to serialize the `IList`

NameValue is an object that have 2 public properties (name and value)

Answer (score 1):

This C# 4 snippet should serialize your collection to a JSON string:

```
"[" +
string.Join(",",
  from nv in list
  select string.Format("{{ name: {0}, value: {1} }}", nv.Name, nv.Value)
) + 
"]"
```

Comment: Have you tried this for any realistic values of `nv.Name` or `nv.Value`? It would generate invalid JSON for almost anything containing any non-alphanumeric character, for example.

Comment: Timwi, I think this answer should work fine. The question was to find a way to do it, not to find how to validate strings passed in JSON. That should be a separate question. Any other ideas? Giving +1.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) (and possibly Linq-to-Json)?

[Here's an example of Linq-to-Json](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/02/11/linq-to-json-beta.aspx)